# python dataframe number of last consequence rows less than current

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to set number of last consequence rows less than current.

Below is a sample input and the result.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([10,9,8,11,10,11,13], columns=['value'])
df_result = pd.DataFrame([[10,9,8,11,10,11,13], [0,0,0,3,0,1,6]], columns=['value', 'number of last consequence rows less than current'])
```

Is it possible to achieve this without loop?

Otherwise solution with loop would be good.

**More question**

Could I do it with groupby operation, for the following input?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,0],[9,0],[7,0],[8,0],[11,1],[10,1],[11,1],[13,1]], columns=['value','group'])
```

Following printed an error.

```
df.groupby('group')['value'].expanding()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
   value
0     10
1      9
2      8
3     11
4     10
5     13
```

You can use a `cummax` and `expanding` custom function:

```
df['out'] = (df['value'].cummax().expanding()
             .apply(lambda s: s.lt(df.loc[s.index[-1], 'value']).sum())
            )
```

For the particular case of `<` comparison, you can use a much faster trick with numpy. If a value is greater than all previous values, then it is greater than `n` values where `n` is the rank:

```
m = df['value'].lt(df['value'].cummax())
df['out'] = np.where(m, 0, np.arange(len(df)))
```

Output:

```
   value  out
0     10  0.0
1      9  0.0
2      8  0.0
3     11  3.0
4     10  0.0
5     13  5.0
```

##### update: consecutive values

```
df['out'] = (
 df['value'].expanding()
 .apply(lambda s: s.iloc[-2::-1].lt(s.iloc[-1]).cummin().sum())
)
```

Output:

```
   value  out
0     10  0.0
1      9  0.0
2      8  0.0
3     11  3.0
4     10  0.0
5     11  1.0
6     13  6.0
```

Comment: I am sorry to say that I asked with wrong data. I edited the data. Could you please amend the code?

Comment: You are a genius. Can I ask one more question lastly, if you have time? I want to do it with groupby, but simply putting groupby after ['value'] did not work. I modified question.